# Htaccess redirecting dynamic urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am trying to create redirections from the old urls to the new ones and I have a problem how to write appropriate htaccess rules.

old urls

```
domain.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/city,name
domain.com/cat1/cat2/city,name
domain.com/cat1/city,name
```

new urls

```
domain.com/cat1/cat2/cat3?city=name
domain.com/cat1/cat2?city=name
domain.com/cat1?city=name
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^/city,(.*)$ /city=?$1 [L]
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^,]*),(.*)/?$ $1/$2/$3?$4=$5 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^,]*),(.*)/?$ $1/$2?$3=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^,]*),(.*)/?$ $1?$2=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.pl/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain.pl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).domain.pl
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://domain.pl/account/firma/%1 [P,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
 
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can there be multiple commas in old URL? What is your Apache version?

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's edit adding following now.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.pl/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain.pl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).domain.pl
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://domain.pl/account/firma/%1 [P,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^,]*),(.*)/?$ $1/$2/$3?$4=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^,]*),(.*)/?$ $1/$2?$3=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^,]*),(.*)/?$ $1?$2=$3 [L]
</IfModule>
 
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

---

---

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##To deal with domain.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/city,name URLs
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^,]*),(.*)/?$ $1/$2/$3?$4=$5 [L]

##To deal with domain.com/cat1/cat2/city,name URLs
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^,]*),(.*)/?$ $1/$2?$3=$4 [L]

##To deal with domain.com/cat1/city,name URLs
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^,]*),(.*)/?$ $1?$2=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Sth is wrong. ```domain.com/cat1/city,name``` is redirecting to ```domain.com/cat1```

Comment: @gambi, all worked fine for me, when I check URL `http://localhost:80/cat1/city,name` ir rewrites to `http://localhost/cat1?city=name` which looks fine to me as per your shown samples, let me know.

Comment: @gambi, Could you please do let me know on this one? If you get any error etc or you have any other rules in your htaccess file which are causing this error?

Comment: Edited my post - I pasted the htaccess file

Comment: @gambi, could you please put your rules in a single starting and then closing backtick for better visibility purposes.

Comment: @gambi, If you want to remove `www` from each request then please put these 2 rules at top of your htaccess after `RewriteEngine ON` put these 2 `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.pl/$1 [L,R=301]` then place other rules of mine, let me know how it goes then?

Comment: Did not work. Could it be that the redirects inside my application do not allow htaccess redirects to work? Apparently the app reads ```city,name``` as a category that doesn't exist and redirects me to another location. If I have the link domain.com/cat1/cat2/cat3 and cat3 does not exist, the application will redirect 301 me to domain.com/cat1/cat2

Comment: @gambi, I think it should work IMHO, could you please check my EDIT rules once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: I changed as you wrote. Unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this full .htaccess code. Make sure you don't have anything extra apart from this code:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+)\.(domain\.pl)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1/account/firma%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(domain\.pl)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^,]+),([^/]+)/?$ $1?$2=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also make sure to clear your browser cache completely before testing this change.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately it doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Sorry but `doesn't work` is never a good explanation of the problem. Clarify what exactly is not working and what error are you getting.

Comment: Ok, If I type ```domain.com/cat1/city,name``` I get e404. If I type ```domain.com/cat1/cat2/city,name``` it takes me to ```domain.com/cat1/cat2```.
If I type ```domain.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/city,name``` it takes me to ```domain.com/cat1/cat2/cat3```

Comment: These are not directories. These are controller parameters.